# $G$-injective MPS and symmetry-broken phases

Tags: symmetry, symmetry-breaking, spin-chains, tensor-network

First, a little bit of motivation. I was reading the paper "[Matrix Product States and Projected Entangled Pair States](https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.12127)" to try to learn more about [MPS representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_product_state) of symmetry broken states. There's a discussion of the GHZ states $\frac{|{0000...}\rangle \pm |{1111...}\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}$ which are the ground states deep in the symmetry-broken phase of the transverse field Ising model (i.e. the ground states of $-\sum_i \sigma^z_i \sigma^z_{i+1} - h\sum_i \sigma^x_i$ for $h=0$). The GHZ states have $A$ matrices of the form $$A^{[0]} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$ and $$A^{[1]} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

The paper makes the following interesting statement:

> Because the corresponding MPS is not injective, the tensors $A^i$ exhibit
> a non-trivial symmetry $G$ on the virtual level represented by the
> matrices that commute simultaneously with all $A^i$ ($\sigma^z$ in this GHZ
> case). MPS with this property are called $G$-injective. Note that this
> symmetry is dual to the physical symmetry which permutes the blocks
> (represented by $\sigma^x$ in the case under consideration).

I interpret this as follows: being $G$-injective implies there exists a basis on the bond space for which the $A^i$ matrices are block diagonal. The set of block diagonal matrices commutes with symmetry operators that are themselves block diagonal and proportional to the identity on each block. However, it's not clear to me what is meant by the fact that these symmetry operators that commute with the $A$ matrices are "dual" to physical symmetry operators. It seems like the paper is making a claim that the symmetry operators that permute blocks are physical in some sense and related to the symmetry of the phase.

Indeed, $\prod_i \sigma^x_i$ is the symmetry operator for the transverse field Ising model, and $(\sigma^x)^\dagger A^i \sigma^x$ permutes the $1$ by $1$ blocks of the $A^i$ matrices, so it seems like there is a close connection.

My aim is to try to understand the theory above within a symmetry broken phase but away from any special points within that phase. My main interest in the theory above is that at the special GHZ point above, in the physical basis of $\sigma^x$ eigenstates, $|+\rangle$ and $|-\rangle$, we have that $$A^{[+]} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} I$$ and $$A^{[-]} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \sigma^z.$$ This is a special form for the $A$ matrices - it makes them proportional to unitary matrices, and I believe this is related to successfully implementing a teleportation protocol via $\sigma^x$ measurement on the GHZ state. Suppose I am in a symmetry broken phase like that given by $-\sum_i \sigma^z_i \sigma^z_{i+1} - h\sum_i \sigma^x_i$ for very small but nonzero $h$.  In this basis away from the GHZ point but still in the phase, could I always write the $A$ matrices as $A^{[+]} = I \otimes B^{[+]}$ and $A^{[-]} = \sigma^z \otimes B^{[-]}$? Here, the $B$ matrices are arbitrary matrices to help allow my bond-dimension to grow away from the special GHZ point.

Comment: What precisely is your question? The part above the horizontal line - i.e. a better understanding of the paper? Or the part below the horizontal line? If the former, it might help to ask a specific question. If the latter, it might help to make this part of the question more specific.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Thanks for checking. I've tried editing the question to be more specific (last line of the question). Roughly, my motivating interest is whether I could be guaranteed to be able to teleport qubits with $x$ measurements anywhere in the symmetry-broken phase/have at least log 2 measurement-induced entanglement, similarly to how SPT states enjoy certain guarantees, like the $A$ matrices being able to be written as tensor products of Paulis and arbitrary matrices within the Haldane phase connected to AKLT. I suspect it's been answered before, so I was hoping to check this.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch The more I think on this, I think the answer to my question has to be no, that I cannot write the $A$ matrices in such a form. If I could, I'd be tempted I could run teleportation, but that would require $\log(2)$ localizable entanglement, and I think the localizable entanglement is strictly less than that away from the special GHZ point.

Comment: I'd say yes: In the symmetry broken phase, and assuming you have the symmetric ground state (!), such as the GHZ state at zero field, there is log(2) (for a Z2 symmetry) localizable entanglement. I'm not sure whether you can localize it on single sites, and with single-site measurements, though (even though I would suspect yes), or whether you need measurements acting on blocks of the order of the corr. length. -- The basic reasoning (even w/out MPS) is that you always have a GHZ-like superposition of two symmetry broken states, and those are orthogonal locally (on the scale of the corr. len.)

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0411123: *"For both spin-1/2 and spin-1 systems we prove that the localizable entanglement of a pure quantum state can be lower bounded by connected correlation functions."* So: long-range order (in the sense of connected correlations) implies localizable entanglement.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Thanks for the comments. That makes sense about blocking sites on the order of the symmetry broken states' correlation length, which appears sufficient to me. It's probably necessary as well; arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0503021 shows that the localizable entanglement (localizable down to two sites) for the TFIM is equal to the lower bound (see under equation 7), and so it's strictly less than log(2) away from the GHZ point.

Comment: Nice find. Though the question remains whether the correlation length appears in the measurements, the spins on which the log(2) entanglement localizes, or both.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Thanks for the discussion, I found the answer to my question with help from Frank Pollmann. Looks like one can use single-site measurements to propagate a protected subspace in the bond space, so the correlation length must be appearing for the spins on which the $\log(2)$ localizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Suppose I am in a symmetry broken phase like that given by $-\sum_i
>  \sigma^z_i \sigma^z_{i+1} - h\sum_i \sigma^x_i$ for very small but
> nonzero $h$.  In this basis away from the GHZ point but still in the
> phase, could I always write the $A$ matrices as $A^{[+]} = I \otimes
>  B^{[+]}$ and $A^{[-]} = \sigma^z \otimes B^{[-]}$?

The answer is yes, and I thank Frank Pollmann for a useful discussion. Note that in the symmetry broken phase, we can construct two symmetry-broken ground states in the thermodynamic limit. One symmetry broken ground state will be mostly up, with scattered downs, and the other will be mostly down, with scattered ups.

The mostly up state will be $$|\psi_u\rangle = \sum_{i_1,...,i_L} \text{Tr}[A_u^{[i_1]}A_u^{[i_2]}...A_u^{[i_L]}] |i_1 i_2,...,i_L\rangle$$
and the mostly down state will be
$$|\psi_d\rangle = \sum_{i_1,...,i_L} \text{Tr}[A_d^{[i_1]}A_d^{[i_2]}...A_d^{[i_L]}] |i_1 i_2,...,i_L\rangle$$

Note that the MPS matrices are related to one another by the symmetry transformation $\prod_i \sigma^x_i$, which interchanges the two symmetry broken ground states: $$A_u^{[0]} = A_d^{[1]}\,\,\text{ and }A_u^{[1]} = A_d^{[0]} $$

The symmetric ground state will be a cat state built out of an MPS with the direct sum of these matrices:

$$|\psi_c\rangle = \sum_{i_1,...,i_L} \text{Tr}[\begin{pmatrix} A_u^{[i_1]} & 0 \\ 0 & A_d^{[i_1]} \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} A_u^{[i_2]} & 0 \\ 0 & A_d^{[i_2]} \end{pmatrix}...\begin{pmatrix} A_u^{[i_L]} & 0 \\ 0 & A_d^{[i_L]} \end{pmatrix}] |i_1 i_2,...,i_L\rangle$$

Let's call the MPS in the symmetric cat state $$A_c^{[i]} = \begin{pmatrix} A_u^{[i]} & 0 \\ 0 & A_d^{[i]} \end{pmatrix}$$

Note that $$A_c^{[+]} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left( \begin{pmatrix} A_u^{[0]} & 0 \\ 0 & A_d^{[0]} \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} A_u^{[1]} & 0 \\ 0 & A_d^{[1]} \end{pmatrix} \right) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix} A_u^{[0]}+A_u^{[1]} & 0 \\ 0 & A_d^{[0]}+A_d^{[1]} \end{pmatrix}$$ and note that we can use the relationship between $A_u$ and $A_d$ to rewrite $A_d^{[0]}+A_d^{[1]}$ as $A_u^{[0]}+A_u^{[1]}$, giving

$$A_c^{[+]} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix} A_u^{[0]}+A_u^{[1]} & 0 \\ 0 & A_u^{[0]}+A_u^{[1]} \end{pmatrix} = I \otimes \frac{A_u^{[0]}+A_u^{[1]}}{\sqrt{2}}.  $$

A similar computation shows that

$$A_c^{[-]} = \sigma^z \otimes \frac{A_u^{[0]}-A_u^{[1]}}{\sqrt{2}}.$$

These are exactly of the postulated form, confirming the guess.